# Python windows forms application

Tags: python-3.x

I want to do some applications with python, but I haven't found any way of getting a tool-box of buttons, check box, etc.
Can some explain me please how can I do that with:
1. Pycharm.
2. If it is problem with Pycharm, visual studio community is also okay.
Thanks,
Ayal

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found:
There is a designer from QT, to build a ui file. There is a tool for translating the ui into python. Then you can edit the logic, with any python tool. You only need PyQt the current version is PyQt5.